# HTML5 responsive website, need autoscroll in small screens to skip aside navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

My website has aside navigation bar. When viewed in the mobile screen if any user clicks on any page, the same header pops up and the user will not know that content is below the header. Hence, I need auto-scroll functionality only to be active on small screen. I searched through a number of websites but cannot find the solution as in how can we use JS script with media queries. Thanks in advance for any help.

**I have code as follows in my JS file but this code scrolls it on all the screen size**

```
function pageScroll() 
{
window.scrollBy(0,1500); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
}
```

**html file**

```
<body onload="pageScroll">
```

But I want to modify this to work only for the mobile screen.

Answer (score 0):

Without any other code to get a good idea of what is happening on your site, you can replicate media queries in jquery like this

```
$("body").on("load",function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768 ) { // mobile devices change it how you want

       window.scrollBy(0,1500); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments

    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! Please let me know what do you need as the part of the code.I did try this but it doesnt work. So this code should go in the js file correct?

Comment: @Palak well, did you try this solution ?

Comment: Yes, I added this to the javascript section and ran my code to see it in mobile view.

Comment: @Palak And? what happened? :)) Anyway, i changed the code a little bit in my answer. Remove the function from js and from html and put the code i gave you. Also, keep in mind...this is jQuery not simple javascript. You need to have JQ library loaded

Comment: I add this code at the end of my index.html before body tag ends. I have this  Jquery file already in my index.html file. .
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>                            When I reduce the size of browser window and click on the navigation link it doesnt scroll down. Should I send the index.html file? or http://drresham.in is the weblink. My site is live but need this autoscroll working. Thanks so much for helping me out

Comment: @Palak after you resize the window. refresh. then try to click

Comment: its the  v2.1.3 file of jquery? is it fine?                                                           /*! jQuery v2.1.3 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */

Comment: I did that testing but it doesnt work for some reason. I have added this this in the head section:                                                                    
                   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on('load',function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768 ) { // mobile devices change it how you want

       window.scrollBy(0,1500); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments

    }
   });
   });
  </script>

Comment: init.js:112 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mixItUp is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (init.js:112)
    at j (jquery.min.js:sourcemap:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:sourcemap:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:sourcemap:2)
    at HTMLDocument.I (jquery.min.js:sourcemap:2)

Comment: This is the error it is showing up but its not related to my code I believe.

Comment: Also it is now giving me: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at index.html:64

Comment: hi Mihai - I tried this:                                          
        $("#page1").click(function() {
    //if ($(window).width() < 768 ) { // mobile devices change it how you want
     txt += "Window width/height: " + $(window).width();
     txt += "x" + $(window).height();
     console.log(txt);
       window.scrollBy(0,900); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments

    //}
   });                                   but for some reason it is not running my script and not showing any console log. Thanks for your help! Let me know if you find anything incorrect here.